# Matlab: copy subrange of cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I want to copy a sub range of a cell array to another one, as I do it for matrices.
Here is the snippet:

```
T_Values_16_17{16,1:11}=T_Values{16,1:11}
```

It lead to error:

> Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but
>   there were 11 results

Doing this one by one like below is possible but I want a shortcut. What is the right syntax for this?

```
T_Values_16_17{16,1}=T_Values{16,1}
T_Values_16_17{16,2}=T_Values{16,2}
...
T_Values_16_17{16,11}=T_Values{16,11}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are two alternatives:

```
[T_Values_16_17{16,1:11}] = T_Values{16,1:11};

T_Values_16_17(16,1:11) = T_Values(16,1:11);
```

Comment: I tried 2nd syntax but it does not worked as expected.

Comment: What are the input and the expected output?

Comment: @VSB You should provide a minimal example